# Monodromy of Legendre family of elliptic curves

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, elliptic-curves

Consider the map $f$ sending the family of elliptic curves $M=\{(x,y,s): y^2=(x-1)(x^2-s): s\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0,1\}\}$ to $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0,1\}$ via
$(x,y,s)\mapsto s$.

This is a locally trivial fibration, hence induces a monodromy action $\rho$ of
$\pi_1(\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0,1\}, p)$ on $H_1(E,\mathbb{Z})$ where $E=f^{-1}(p)$
and $p\ne 0,1$.

I am trying to understand the argument of Calson, Müller-Stach and Peters in their book Period Mappings and Period Domains, [page 18](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=XrYrDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA3&pg=PA18#v=onepage&q&f=false) of how they deduce the monodromy action explicitly. In particular,

- Let $a,b\in 
  \pi_1(\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0,1\})$ be closed loops at $p$ around $0,1$, respectively, then $\pi_1(\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0,1\})=\langle a,b\rangle$.
- One can determine a basis for $H_1(E,\mathbb{Z})$ as follows: consider $\mathbb{P}^1\setminus \{1,\pm \sqrt{p},\infty\}$, and draw two line segments $c_1,c_2$
  connecting $\sqrt{p}$ with $-\sqrt{p}$ and $1$ with $\infty$. These are the branch cuts for
  our function $y=\sqrt{(x^2-p)(x-1)}$.
  Let $\delta$ be a closed loop going around
  $c_1$ and $\gamma$ be a closed loop passing through both $c_1$ and $c_2$.
  Their preimages under $f$ intersect with $E$ to form two loops around two holes
  of the torus $E$ (see page 6 of their book for more explanation).

My question is:

> How to show that the monodromy action of $a$ on $H_1(E,\mathbb{Z})$
> with respect to basis $\delta, \gamma$ is
> $\rho(a)(\delta)=\delta, \rho(a)(\gamma)=\delta+\gamma$?

What I gather so far: Start with the locally trivial fibration
$f:M\to \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0,1\}$ and $a:[0,1]\to \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0,1\}$
a closed loop of $p$ around $0$, then $a^*f$ is a fiber bundle on
$[0,1]$, hence is a trivial bundle. This means there exists a
family of diffeomorphisms $f_t: f^{-1}(a(t))\to f^{-1}(p)$ such that $f_0$
is the identity map. The diffeomorphism $f_1$ then induces an isomorphism
on the homology $H_1(E,\mathbb{Z})\to H_1(E,\mathbb{Z})$, which is our
monodromy action. However, how to describe $f_1$ explicitly?

PS: It seems that this goes under the name of Picard–Lefschetz transformation,
but I don't know what this is, and would love to hear an explanation of this
using the above example. Or I would be very happy if someone could point out
an easy place to read about this. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, but Kodaira classified the singular fibers of elliptic fibrations, along with the associated monodromy actions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_surface#Monodromy . You can use Tate's algorithm to determine the types of the singular fibers and then just look up the monodromy in the linked table.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn Thanks for telling me this, but this is not what I want. However, it seems the book referenced in that wikipedia link has some explanation about Picard–Lefschetz transformation.